# How to initiate addin code on .BeforeClose() event

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I am trying to build my first excel addin that would initiate a code on close of the workbook once certain condition is met. The condition is checked by the on error go to end.

When I run my addin, it looks like this entire part of code does not get initiated.

This code is currently stored in the ThisWorkbook of the add-in.

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Integer

    On Error GoTo ENDING
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ADDIN-

DONOTTOUCH").Cells(1.1).Value)
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb1.ActiveSheet
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

.....'Other code....

wb1.Save
wb1.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ADDIN-DONOTTOUCH").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ENDING:
End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW you're discarding the opened workbook; capture the reference instead of assuming the opened book is the active workbook - `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't ever be typing event handler procedure signatures by hand.

> ```
> Private WithEvents App As Application
> ```

This `WithEvents` variable adds an `App` entry in the code pane's left-hand dropdown:

[image: App variable in the LHS dropdown]

Select it. Now expand the right-hand dropdown...

[image: available events for the App event source]

When you select a member in the RHS dropdown, the VBE automatically creates the handler procedure for you, *and it is guaranteed to be valid and well-formed*. Whereas if you type them from memory, a mistake in parameter ordering can cause a lot of grief.

In any case, the `Excel.Application` object does not expose a `BeforeClose` event, so while your procedure *looks* like an event handler, the LHS dropdown says **(General)** (instead of an event source object), and the "handler" is never actually invoked.

But, since `ThisWorkbook` is an add-in, it will be loaded along with Excel, and unless unloaded manually, will be unloaded *also* along with Excel - so if you handle `Workbook.BeforeClose` in `ThisWorkbook`, then you'll get to run custom code when Excel closes your add-in - *whether because the add-in is being unloaded, or because Excel is shutting down*.